# How to ask questions for software that doesn't have a tag yet?

Tags: support, tags

We use [StreamServe](http://www.streamserve.com/) as our OMS and I want to start a discussion on StackOverflow but there is no adequate tag. Is there a way to create a tag without 1500 points reputation?

Comment: Also if you'll post the LINK to the question others might retag without having to dig ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**

There isn't. If the tag is relevant, someone with enough reputation will retag the question to include it. Also, be careful with posting a discussion. If it is not a direct question with regards to a programming problem with the software, it will most likely get closed, and creating the tag would be useless anyway.

Comment: Okay I see - it seems there are to few users at stackoverflow for my programming related question.

Comment: @MarcelJanus then you'll be the first and can start a knowledge base for those who come after.